# `?` couldn't convert the error to `std::io::Error`

Tags: rust, reqwest

I am attempting to do a post using the reqwest library and following patters that I have found in various places online:

```
let res = http_client.post(&url)
                          .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                          .form(&form_data)
                          .send()
                          .await?;
println!("authenticate response: {}", res.status)
```

The code block above causes a compile error:

```
`?` couldn't convert the error to `std::io::Error` the trait ` 
      `std::convert::From<reqwest::error::Error>` is not implemented for `std::io::Error`
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error.  I have made my code as close to the examples as I can.  It will compile if I remove the `?` and the `res.status`.  But I need to get the status `res.status` value.  More importantly, I need to understand what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct error part of the Result type of a function propagating different error types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62100863/what-is-the-correct-error-part-of-the-result-type-of-a-function-propagating-diff)

Comment: @E_net4onMetatoomuchtime thanks for the link.  It does add some background , but the answer below did directly solve my problem.  Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your error is caused by the return type of the function from where you call this block, the compiler wants to return a error of the type `std::io::Error`.

From the error description, I draw the conclusion your `main` function looks something like this:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that reqwest does not return an `io::Error`. This is a snippet I wrote a few months ago:

```
use exitfailure::ExitFailure;

fn main() -> Result<(), ExitFailure> {
    let res = http_client
        .post(&url)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .form(&form_data)
        .send()
        .await?;

    println!("authenticate response: {}", res.status);
    Ok(())
}
```

I used [exitfailure](https://docs.rs/exitfailure/0.5.1/exitfailure/) to convert the returned error type to a human-readable return type for `main`. I think it will solve your issue too.

***Update:***
It was pointed out in the comments, exifailure have deprecated dependencies and this could be achieved without an external crate. There is a recommended way of returning an encapsulated dynamic error: `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let res = http_client
        .post(&url)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .form(&form_data)
        .send()
        .await?;

    println!("authenticate response: {}", res.status);
    Ok(())

}
```

From what I could see the behavior in returning agreageted errors from `main` is identical.

Comment: `Box<dyn Error>` is [recommended by the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#the--operator-can-be-used-in-functions-that-return-result) and avoids extra dependencies.

Comment: Especially since `exitfailure` depends on `failure`, which is [deprecated](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/failure#failure---a-new-error-management-story).

Comment: TIL, thanks! The root cause of the problem is as I wrote.

Comment: I will check my code from this old project and correct my answer tonight when I have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

`map_err` is used to convert the error types in Rust. its closure takes the error from the `Result` error and converts it to a new error. if you use in your project and hover over it, you see this

> Maps a Result<T, E> to Result<T, F> by applying a function to a
> contained Err value, leaving an Ok value untouched.
>
> This function can be used to pass through a successful result while
> handling an error.

```
use std::io::{Error,ErrorKind};


let res = http_client.post(&url)
                          .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                          .form(&form_data)
                          .send()
                          .await; // removed ?
                          // ErrorKind is enum. you could choose different options
                          .map_err(|err|Error::new(ErrorKind::Other,"could not do post req"))?;
```